# Removing Elements from Form by Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, getelementsbyclassname

When trying to remove elements from the form by their class in Javascript, for some reason it is removing every other element. I have absolutely no clue what is causing this behavior and hope someone can point out where my flawed logic is with this.

I just want to leave the first element (inv0) and remove all of the rest, but using the exact code below, it leaves me with inv0, inv2 and inv4.

JS:

```
function clearInventoryFields()
{
    // Get the element by their class name
    var invFields = document.getElementsByClassName('inventory');

    for (var i = 1; i < invFields.length; i++)
    {
        invFields[i].parentNode.removeChild(invFields[i]);
    }
}
```

The HTML looks as follows...

```
<fieldset style="width:62%; float:left; margin-left: 19%;">
<div id="inv0" class="inventory" style="margin-bottom:5px;"> … </div>
<div id="inv1" class="inventory" style="margin-bottom:5px;"> … </div>
<div id="inv2" class="inventory" style="margin-bottom:5px;"> … </div>
<div id="inv3" class="inventory" style="margin-bottom:5px;"> … </div>
<div id="inv4" class="inventory" style="margin-bottom:5px;"> … </div>
<div id="inv5" class="inventory" style="margin-bottom:5px;"> … </div>
</fieldset>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing it the other way round

```
for (var i = invFields.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
```

- see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7G5YP/).  It works the way you would like it to.

Comment: Why is the original code failing?

Comment: The issue is this - invFields.length is evaluated at the start of the for loop.  Subsequently you remove child elements and invFields get shorter.  The result is that the loop is trying to index elements that no longer exist.

Comment: I discovered this, just wondering why the code did not throw an exception.

Comment: @Marc Audet - Actually, my comment above is not entirely correct.  The loop never "tries" to index non-existent elements.  It just stops looping!  See this fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/7G5YP/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/7G5YP/2/)

Comment: What saves the situation is that `invFields.length` keeps the index value in a valid range, good illustrative demo, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I can figure out is,

```
$('.inventory:gt(0)').each(function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

### [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2JNpR/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
function clearInventoryFields()
{
    // Get the element by their class name
    var invFields = document.getElementsByClassName('inventory');

    for (var i = invFields.length-1; i >= 1 ; i--)
    {
      invFields[i].parentNode.removeChild(invFields[i]);
    }
}
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/AyazEl/1

Comment: Why is the original code failing?

Comment: In your code, the loop remove the `i` item from the array starting from 0. For example, the first iteration (`i = 1`), remove the second item in the parent node. But on the next iteration, where `i = 2`, the parent node dont contains the previous removed item. So, you delete the third item. etc